# Customizing Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I had a Response coming like a JSON array like below and I need to sort out the JSON containing the same roleId and TenantId and send them with all the features in the same array.

```
[
    {
        "roleId": 1,
        "role": "admin",
        "featureId": 1,
        "feature": "Dashboard",
        "tenantId": 1,
        "tenant": "Admin"
    },
    {
        "roleId": 1,
        "role": "admin",
        "featureId": 2,
        "feature": "Overview",
        "tenantId": 1,
        "tenant": "Admin"
    },
    {
        "roleId": 1,
        "role": "admin",
        "featureId": 3,
        "feature": "Devices",
        "tenantId": 1,
        "tenant": "Admin"
    },
    {
        "roleId": 1,
        "role": "admin",
        "featureId": 4,
        "feature": "Map View",
        "tenantId": 1,
        "tenant": "Admin"
    }
]
```

I need to customize it and return as a response like below grouping by tenantid and role in a sub json

```
{
    "roleId": 1,
    "role": "admin",
    "features": [
        {
            "featureId": 1,
            "feature": "Dashboard"
        },
        {
            "featureId": 2,
            "feature": "Overview",
        },
        {
            "featureId": 4,
            "feature": "Map View",
        },
        {
            "featureId": 3,
            "feature": "Devices",
        }
    ],
    "tenantId": 1,
    "tenant": "Admin"
},
{
    "roleId": 2,
    "role": "monitor",
    "features": [
        {
            "featureId": 1,
            "feature": "Dashboard"
        },
        {
            "featureId": 2,
            "feature": "Overview",
        },
        {
            "featureId": 4,
            "feature": "Map View",
        },
        {
            "featureId": 3,
            "feature": "Devices",
        }
    ],
    "tenantId": 1,
    "tenant": "Admin"
}
```

Expected UI should be something like below after integration

[UI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW90f.png)

Please help me out in this

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can not have same index in your desired output array. they will get overWritten [`feature`,`featureId` ... etc]. See here:- https://3v4l.org/Ze2SY

Comment: Its not possible to achieve the response in below

Comment: That can't be parsed back to an array later, you know that? An array can only have one key with the same name in the same subarray

Comment: I have changed the required response, can you please look @AlivetoDie

Comment: Tqs for the two way array binding solution  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You need to decode your json data using [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

2.Then you need to use [foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop this data

3.Now create a new array and assign values to this array inside loop by making  `roleId` as array keys[so that same `roleId` values will goes to same child-array automatically]

4.Now do [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to re-index the final array

5.Encode this using [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to get desired format.

Code:-

```
$array = json_decode( $json , true);

$final_array = array();

foreach($array as $arr){
    $final_array[$arr['roleId']]['roleId'] = $arr['roleId'];
    $final_array[$arr['roleId']]['role'] = $arr['role'];
    $final_array[$arr['roleId']]['feature'][] = array('featureId'=>$arr['featureId'],'feature'=>$arr['feature']);
}

$final_array = array_values($final_array);
echo json_encode($final_array);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/CuCI2